# How do I add a column to the Spotify List (using API 1.5.1)

Tags: jquery, spotify

Using the Spotify API and the List.

How do I add a new column and then sort it?
I want to get the BPM from echo nest and show them in the grid.

I don't want to use a custom gird as the Spotify one has select/play etc.

It looks like the List is lazy but setting 'greedy' doesn't work. Should I try and sort the model instead of the table?

Thanks

https://github.com/mikeblakeuk/echofy

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately adding custom columns and sorting lists is not supported yet. It is however on our radar and something that we will add support for.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Ok thanks. I assume that it would also be better to be adding datat o the tracks and not the grid directly. Do you have any sameples of this? I've managed to fin the 'views-tutorial' (which I suggest is commited to github) but that doesn't really show how to extend it.

Comment: Also, should greedy load all of the rows AND the html table?